# python/briefcase problem on pyproject.toml

Tags: python, android

pyproject.toml

```ini
[tool.briefcase]
app = "app_name"
description = "description"
author = "name"
email = "email"
version = "0.1.0"
```

run command "briefcase run android " and terminal write me error

```
Log saved to C:\Users\ruper\PycharmProjects\StrongBudy\logs\briefcase.2023_04_13-14_49_04.run.log

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 198, in _run_module_as_main
  File "<frozen runpy>", line 88, in _run_code
  File "C:\Users\ruper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts\briefcase.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\ruper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\briefcase\__main__.py", line 24, in main
    command.parse_config(Path.cwd() / "pyproject.toml")
  File "C:\Users\ruper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\briefcase\commands\base.py", line 716, in parse_config
    global_config, app_configs = parse_config(
                                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\ruper\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\briefcase\config.py", line 543, in parse_config
    for app_name, app_data in all_apps.items():
                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

I don't know how to solve it

Comment: Currently, at this time it is impossible to determine what you are doing with so little. May I suggest you read, [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Please expand your question to include context, the reason for your question, the expected result, (maybe) what functions and versions you are running, etc.

Answer (score 0):

As well as the `tool.briefcase` section in pyproject.toml, Briefcase also requires a `tool.briefcase.app` section. The easiest way to set this up is to use the `briefcase new` command. See the [BeeWare tutorial](https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-1.html) for full instructions.