# AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items' (python) (briefcase)

Tags: python-3.x

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                                   
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main    
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\Program Files\Python38\lib\runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\mpgam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\briefcase\__main__.py", line 66, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())  # pragma: no cover
  File "C:\Users\mpgam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\briefcase\__main__.py", line 25, in main
    command.parse_config(
  File "C:\Users\mpgam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\briefcase\commands\base.py", line 831, in parse_config
    global_config, app_configs = parse_config(
  File "C:\Users\mpgam\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\briefcase\config.py", line 483, in parse_config
    for app_name, app_data in all_apps.items():
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'items'
```

When i try to run the command `python -m briefcase dev`
And i have the needed briefcase.toml file and pyproject.toml

I tried to remove the files and make new ones again but nothing works.

Answer (score 0):

Judging from the message, it sounds like the variable all_apps mentioned at the bottom of the error is a string and not a dictionary, which is probably the result of a misconfiguration. Per [the BeeWare tutorial](https://docs.beeware.org/en/latest/tutorial/tutorial-1.html), pyproject.toml also requires a `tool.briefcase.app` section, and the `briefcase new` command will create that for you.

See the same issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76005660/python-briefcase-problem-on-pyproject-toml).